# Trying to understand masking

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, mask

I've been trying to understand masking and how it works with image filters. I'm using the following code to try to develop my understanding.

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#   Generate a random binary mask
np.random.seed(seed=182)
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(901, 877))

img = np.random.rand(901, 877)

img_masked = np.ma.masked_array(img, mask = mask)
img_masked_filtered = ndi.median_filter(img_masked, size=10)
img_unmasked_filtered = ndi.median_filter(img, size=10)

median_masked = np.ma.median(img_masked)
median_unmasked = np.ma.median(img)
```

In the results, median_unmasked != median_masked as I expect, but img_masked_filtered == img_unmasked_filtered which I don't want. scipy.ndimage.median_filter does exactly the job I need, but it doesn't work with masked images. What can I use that will do the same thing as the median filter, but which will work on a masked image?

The weird size I'm using for the array is because that's the size of the image I eventually want to filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ndimage filters do not respect masked arrays' masks. Instead, "mask" an ordinary NumPy array with `nan` values, and then use [`ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html) to call `np.nanmedian`:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=182)
# h, w = 901, 877
h, w = 10, 10
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(h, w))
img = np.random.rand(h, w)
img_masked = np.where(mask, img, np.nan)

size = 3
img_masked_median = ndi.generic_filter(img_masked, np.nanmedian, size=size)
img_unmasked_median = ndi.median_filter(img, size=size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax[0,0].imshow(img)
ax[0,0].set_title('img')
ax[0,1].imshow(img_masked)
ax[0,1].set_title('img_masked')
ax[1,0].imshow(img_unmasked_median)
ax[1,0].set_title('img_unmasked_median')
ax[1,1].imshow(img_masked_median)
ax[1,1].set_title('img_masked_median')
plt.show()
```

[image]